# potential leak of an object stored into cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-leaks

Please don't make it as duplicate as there are many question and answer which refer to my question. But I am not able to found my error from their answer.

My project is under ARC. I have implemented the below method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UITableViewCountryPickerCellIdentifier];

    if(!cell) cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:UITableViewCountryPickerCellIdentifier];

    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:BDS_FONT size:BDS_FONT_SIZE_TITLE_16]];
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor lightBlackColor]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:(NSString *)[countryArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

Where on `return cell` Xcode anlyzer shows `potential leak of an object stored into cell` and on expanding it show something like below

[image]

I can't understand what to do. Can anybody help me what's happening.

This code is under CountryPickerViewController.m and ARC is enable for this file.
[image]

Comment: Code looks fine to me. I've used that same code in dozens of table views without issue.

Comment: I think it should be `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, not `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier `

Comment: You have ARC turned off for this file. Check the file-specific compiler flags.

Comment: @KudoCC Sorry that was my mistake but after change it to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` still the problem remain..

Comment: @JoshCaswell I cross checked ARC is active for whole project.

Comment: Check the file-specific compiler flags.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Can you please check my updated question and also elaborate regarding the answer, and can you unmark it `duplicate` tag as the provide answer is not solving my issue.

Comment: Add an `autorelease` to your `return` line. `return [cell autorelease];` and then re-analyze.

Comment: ARC not allow me to add autorelease

Comment: What was the error it gave you?

Comment: autorelease is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: The analyzer should not be giving this warning if the file is compiled with ARC; this is exactly the kind of thing that ARC handles. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Xcode version is 6.1.1 and @josh as you can't resolve it so can you unmark the duplicate tag so that other can help me.

Comment: I reopened the question two minutes ago.